# Viewing page tables in filesystem

Tags: ram

I know that the page table is managed by the linux kernel, though I am not sure if it is available on the filesystem.  I'd like to view information about page tables from the command line.

As background, I've been learning about page tables and how they are critical to managing processes, where each process is assigned its own address space so that process A cannot write to process B's memory space.

Essentially, the page table maps between virtual addresses and physical addresses.

I would like to actually view from the command line this mapping to see how it works.  Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this fits better on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @LeopoldoPla perhaps different distros have it located in different locations. I'm on ubuntu.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069620/print-kernels-page-table-entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the closest you are going to get is /proc/PID/maps, which the `pmap` utility reads and reformats so it is a bit easier to read.  It shows the ranges of virtual memory and their permissions, and what file, if any, they are mapped to, but not the current virtual->physical mappings.